# maven pom's resource element

Tags: maven, pom.xml

i am new to maven and came across the resources section. The reference for the maven project descriptor (version 4.0) states that "this element describes all of the classpath resources associated with a project or unit tests" ([link](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-model/maven.html#class_resource)). However this description i do not understand/seems to abstract for me. Why would i want to describe classpath resources? How does it affect the projects lifecycle?

matthias

Answer (score 11, accepted):

usually you have the src/main/resources folder which contains resources which will be packaged into a jar. This everything which is in the above folder will automatically be packaged into a jar and is accessible via getResource... Via the resources area in the pom you can [filter files from their way src/main/resources to the target/classes folder](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

```
<project>
  ...
  <name>My Resources Plugin Practice Project</name>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

The lifecycle of Maven is not influenced by this.

Comment: I have added resources successfully in .Jar file. But when I am trying to execute Jar file on other machine it's trying to fetch testng.xml and log4j2.xml files with my local path only. Can you please help me how to add paths for tesng.xml in surefire pulgin? My detailed question is here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56353362/selenium-maven-testng-how-can-we-add-testng-parameters-in-java-class-while-ad)

Answer (score 1):

This feature allows you, for example, to use Maven variables inside your .properties files. Just declare the directory, where your .properties are, in `<resources>` section, and you'll be able to use ${project.name} or whatever.

pom.xml:

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

version.properties:

```
version=${pom.version}
timestamp=${timestamp}
```

(${timestamp} is created with Maven Build Number plugin).