# Selenium - Maven/TestNG: how can we add testng parameters in Java class while adding "main method" to create executable /runnable.jar file?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jar, testng

I have project with TestNG, Maven.

I am passing parameters in testng.xml file. Added "main method" for testng config to create executable .jar file.

I have referred -- [Running TestNG programmatically](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically). But no method is present there for passing parameters or maybe I have missed that one.

This is how my main method looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 ExtentReportListener extentReport = new ExtentReportListener();
 TestNG testng = new TestNG();
 testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] {FirstTest.class});
 testng.addListener(extentReport);
 testng.run();
}
```

Please help me out to pass parameters in main method itself. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have `String[] args`. It's array of passed parameters. So if you're running:

java -jar your_jar.jar param1 param2

you automatically obtain args[0]="param1" and args[1]="param2"

You also can use a system properties.

Running

java -jar your_jar.jar -Dparam1=12 -Dparam2=13

You can call `System.getProperty("param1")` from anywhere and it will return you "12".

And... Imho the best way to run TestNG project programmaticaly is using of maven/gradle surefire plugin.

Comment: So if I use that maven plugin, then I can share executable .jar file across my teams or they will need to have testng.xml on their local machine?

Comment: 1. You can pack your xml into jar even without surefire. 2. Check this, how to avoid using testng.xml with surefire: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Comment: how can I achieve that? Cause I am using log4j2.xml as well. Don't know how I can bundle them and share only .Jar file to my team mates? let me know if you want me to post separate question for this.

Comment: For example using maven resource plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html